# Scapy's sniff() function does not capture all packets

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy

I have written a Python program that uses Scapy to capture all the traffic from/to a specific port on the local host, i.e., loopback (the purpose being trying to quantify the amount of traffic).

It appears, that unlike Wireshark, scapy does not capture all the packets sent, but it rather reports a very small percentage. Is this by design, or am I misconfiguring something?

You see my code below:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.arch.windows import get_windows_if_list
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

conf.use_pcap = True
conf.use_npcap = True


class Capture:
    def __init__(self, interface, filter, timeout, max_packets):
        self.interface = interface
        self.filter = filter
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.max_packets = max_packets
        self.start_sniff_timestamp = 0
        self.plength = np.zeros(max_packets, dtype='int')
        self.ptimediff = np.zeros(max_packets, dtype='float')
        self.ptimestamp = np.zeros(max_packets, dtype='float')
        self.pcount = 0
        self.packet_list = []

    def __del__(self):
        self.capture.clear()
        self.capture.close()

    def process_packets(self, packet):
        try:
            self.plength[self.pcount] = int(len(packet.payload))
            self.ptimestamp[self.pcount] = time.time()
            self.pcount += 1
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    def capture_packets(self, timeout = None):
        if timeout == None:
            timeout = self.timeout

        print(f"**** Start capturing at {time.time()}")

        self.capture = sniff(filter=self.filter, iface=self.interface,
                     prn=self.process_packets, count=self.max_packets, timeout=self.timeout)
        print(f"**** Stop capturing at {time.time()}")
        print(f"     Total packets: {self.pcount} ")

    def get_interfaces(self):
        interfaces = get_windows_if_list()
        for interface in interfaces:
            print(interface)

    def plot(self, inteval=1):
        if self.pcount == 0:
            print("Nothing to plot")
            return
        t = np.array(self.ptimestamp[:self.pcount]) - self.ptimestamp[0]
        d = np.array(self.plength[:self.pcount])
        interval = 1

        bin_edges = np.arange(t[0], t[-1] + interval, interval)

        # Calculate the indices of the bins to which each value in time belongs
        bin_indices = np.digitize(t, bin_edges)

        # t[bin_indices==1]
        unique_bin_indices = np.array(list(set(bin_indices)), dtype='float')
        unique_bin_indices.sort()

        sum_per_interval = np.array([d[bin_indices == i].sum() for i in unique_bin_indices])
        mean_per_sec = sum_per_interval / interval

        plt.close('all')
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.plot(t, d, '.g')
        ax.set_ylabel('Packet Info')
        ax.yaxis.label.set_color('green')

        ax1 = ax.twinx()
        ax1.plot(unique_bin_indices * interval, sum_per_interval, 'r*')
        ax1.set_ylabel('Sum Per Interval')
        ax1.yaxis.label.set_color('red')
        plt.show()

capt = Capture(
    interface='\\Device\\NPF_Loopback',
    filter="port 61616",
    timeout=100,
    max_packets=10000)

capt.capture_packets()
capt.plot(1)
print('The end')
```